# aggregate target + target paths

Tags: xcode6

For one of my schemes I want to copy 2 folders into the final app bundle. For that I created an aggregate target with a copy build phase and added that target to the scheme where it should be triggered. That works fine, except for the target paths.

I appears something with the target paths is wrong however. In the copy build phase I can select whatever pre defined path exists in the drop down, the folder always end up in the same place ("Myproject/DerivedData/Myproject/Build/Products/Debug") instead of the app bundle. Is there something special to consider for aggregate targets?

I also tried to set a subpath with one of the build variables. They don't seem to be set however and have no effect. Setting a manual path works however. Though, I don't want to hard code my apps bundle name + Contents etc. if the normal way is usually to use an env var.

Btw. I also tried a script phase and checked the env vars printed in the build log. None contains the path to my app bundle (or parts of it below the Debug folder).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it has to do with the target type (aggregate target), I don't know. I couldn't get the predefined paths to work, they always seem to be empty. So, I ended up by hard coding the relative path (which rarely changes). But that is of course asking for trouble if I ever change the project's name.